# Store a large pandas dataframe into a csv file

Tags: dataframe

I have a large data frame of three lists of 5942620 length X, Y, Z. I have to store the data frame into a CSV. The CSV file is created but with only part of the data. Here is the code snippet:

```
    X = [1,2,3,4,....]
    Y = ['á','b','c',...]
    Z = [10,20,30,...]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':X,'y':Y,'z':Z})
    df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

Thanks

Comment: if the length of X Y Z are not the same, you will have that problem. did you check that?

Comment: All have the same length.